# How is multiplying by odd does not lose information in overflow?

Tags: java, binary, hashcode, integer-overflow

The standard approach to calculate a hashcode is to multiply with 31.
Bloch states:

> The value 31 was chosen because it is an odd prime. If it were even
>   and the multiplication overflowed, information would be lost, as
>   multiplication by 2 is same as shifting

I am not sure I understand this. If the multiplication overflows value is lost regardless of even/odd right?
In the following example I am not sure what is the difference:

```
int number = 2000000000;  
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));  
number*=2;   
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));    
1110111001101011001010000000000  
11101110011010110010100000000000
```

and

```
int number = 2000000000;  
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));  
number*=3;  
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(number));  
1110111001101011001010000000000  
1100101101000001011110000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Even numbers always forget *at least* the most significant bit. The msb only affects the result if the multiplier is odd, because only when shifted left by 0 steps does it not immediately disappear. That is also what was meant by "information would be lost, as multiplication by 2 is same as shifting". In your example you don't run into much visible trouble because the result does not overflow, 2000000000 = 0x77359400 clearly does not have the top bit set (it wraps to negative as a signed integer but that's irrelevant, the sign bit is a normal bit that carries a bit of information, shifting something into it doesn't destroy information), working backwards it is ambiguous whether it was 0x77359400 before shifting or 0xF7359400. I hope this is sufficient "intuitive justification".

The real proof that only odd multipliers preserve all information is that it is precisely odd numbers that have multiplicative inverses modulo a power of two. x has a multiplicative inverse modulo m iff gcd(x, m) == 1, given that m is 2<sup>k</sup> that condition holds only for odd numbers: it cannot hold for even numbers because they'd have a factor of 2 in common, and since an odd number has no factors of 2 but 2<sup>k</sup> *only* has factors of 2, they never share any factors.

The fact that there is an inverse `inv(x)` means you can write `number * x * inv(x) = number` so no information could have been lost in the first multiplication.

As a concrete example, `inv(3) = 0xaaaaaaab` so:

```
2000000000 * 3 = 0x65a0bc00
0x65a0bc00 * 0xaaaaaaab = 2000000000
```

Comment: 1) Is there any difference between MSB and sign bit in your explanation? I am not entirely sure. 2) I didn't get the `0xF7359400` part. That's 4147483648 right?

Comment: @Jim 1) not really, it's just that the MSB is sometimes interpreted as a sign bit. 2) yes or -147483648 if you want to interpret it as a signed integer, either way writing it in decimal obscures its relationship to the original number, the point is that shifting something *out* of the MSB means it is lost so the original MSB could have been 0 or 1

Comment: So multiplication by an odd number is always a shift-by-0 step?

Comment: @Jim yes, if you write the multiplication out in binary, the partial product `number << 0` will be included because the LSB of the multiplier is set